# PhpMyAdmin Trigger is not creating with error: 1064

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger on PHPMYADMIN and this query below is not working, it is showing the error:

- "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Contas SET Saldo = Saldo - NEW.Valor_Transferido WHERE Apos' at line 11"

  ```
  delimiter //
  CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_SALDO BEFORE INSERT ON Transferencias
  FOR EACH 
  ROW
  BEGIN
      IF (NEW.Valor_Transferido > 0) THEN

  UPDATE Contas
     SET Saldo = Saldo + NEW.Valor_Transferido 
  WHERE Apostador_ID = NEW.Destino_Apostador_ID

  UPDATE Contas
     SET Saldo = Saldo - NEW.Valor_Transferido 
  WHERE Apostador_ID = NEW.Origem_Apostador_ID

     END IF
  END;
  //
  delimiter ;
  ```

Any idea where on this query is wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the UPDATE statements should be terminated with a semicolon, the END IF should also be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Completely right, put this answer as answer to give you positive. Thank you!!!!